# How can i get rid of the habit of masturbation?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, sex, masturbation

AOA.Iam a boy and, Iam badly addicted to masturbation. First of all I liked these kinds of things from my childhood. Whem I was at the age of about 7 years. I used to watch video songs In whcih i liked to see the girls dancing. At this age a child do not know about such things but I was interested. I liked to watch kissing scenes from movies. But inside i myself did not know about even the relation between a Boy and Girl. Also, My elder cousin used to take me to sleep by telling stories.She was lying beside me telling stories But i was thinking that she is naked in my thoughts. Iam talking about the age of 7. I even did not know that how a girl looks like without clothes. This continued and then i got my first android tablet as a gift. I was about 12 by then. I used to watch some 18+ videos on youtube. Then by browsing here and there i was introduced to Anime pornography. Now i was at least 14 years old. One of my friend told me about hand practice. I did it. And then i was addicted to it. Moreover another friend told me about a real porn website. And since then to now at age of 17. I can't get rid of this habit. It is about one year ago when i came to know that this act is haraam. I tried my best but could not do so. My parents do not know about this at all. Sometimes i even masturbate in my clothes while watching porn. But my parents think that it is just due to normal puberty. I cannot tell them. Please help me. I know this is not good for my future and health. I feel dizzy and lazy all time. I also want to know that why iam interested in these things from my childhood. My mind is always thinking about porn. Pls hellpp me. Tell me some duas and remedies to get rid of this.

Comment: This thread has too many tips for your help: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/59589/masturbation-16-y-o?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 tips for you

1. Stay with a group of people like ur family or friends this will lower the desire to masturbate
2. Get rid of like girls dancing or doing sexual things immediately this is totally prohibited in Islam.
3. Remember Allah is watching you always.

You should not give up that is what shaitan want you to do not think Allah will forgive Allah will forgive if you are sincere in ur repentance just so these things and if you try ur hardest inshallah you will stop this bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum brother,

I understand your problem brother, but please think about [the blessings of *Jannah* and the horrors of *Jahannam*](https://quran.com/18/29-31). Think, if you die while masturbating, what will happen?

Never combine three things - **Loneliness**, **Device** and **Thinking** together. When you realize that your thinking is exceeding the limit, immediately start reciting any memorized verse from the Qur'an. You can memorize the above verses (at least [this verse](https://quran.com/18/29)) with word-by-word meaning. If you fail, start brushing your teeth with a *Miswaak*.

However, the main suggestions are here => *[IslamQA - Ruling on masturbation and how to cure the problem](https://islamqa.info/ur/329)*. Please read it carefully and try to obey all the directions. May Allah rescue every Muslim youth from the devastating habit.