# I need to stop masturbating I am young and don’t want to commit this sin anymore

Tags: halal-haram, zina, masturbation

Ive been trying to stop masturbating In a Long time i stopped but come across it again I make tauba but it comes back I something make dua for my fingers to break because I hate myself after it’s done I need help can anyone show me ways to stop doing it also I am not at the age for marriage which means I am a young person

Comment: Did you take a moment to look at this site and click on the relevant tags before posting this question? If you had, your question would have been well answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Masturbation 16 y/o](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/59589/masturbation-16-y-o)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to leave a **Haram** addiction as long as you still can not leave a **Halal** addiction!
Therefore you must begin to leave/change some of you Halal habits like:

Drinking the morning coffe/tea.

Sleeping on soft bed = sleep on the ground for a week.

Using the right hand = use the left hand in daily affairs for few days.

Eating what you love = smell it, look at it, but give it to someone else to eat it in front of you.

once you've done these actions, your controll on your Nafs becomes strong and that's when you can say NO to your Nafs commanding you to masturbate

PS: that is exactly what Fasting on Ramadhan teaches us. To avoid Halals and change our habits, therefore to gain power to fight against the Nafs. That's why Quran says: **"Seek help from Salat and Fasting"**

Allah be with you.